# Mapping large array is blocking my nodejs thread

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to map a large array(around 11k items). The actual mapping function is super simple, but the amount of items in the array is just too much and it blocks everything.
What's the best approach to avoid this? I tried using Async map, but I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can somehow change the sync (map) operation to an async operation using Promise or setTimeout.  Recursive function can be used to progressively process the items in large array.

For example:

```
const largeArrays = [];
const resultArrays = [];

function process(source, target, index) {
    if (index === target.length) {
        // Now the result Arrays should have all processed data
        return
    }

    // Dummy map action here for example, please change to your own one
    target.push(source[index] + 1);
    setTimeout(() => { process(source, target, index + 1) }, 0);
}

process(largeArrays, resultArrays, 0)
```

You can wrap about code into a Promise and resolve it instead of using the return statement above.

You don't need any fancy library, just native javascript function.  You can check on two of my blogs illustrating ideas for these kinds of problems.
[How to avoid Stack overflow error on recursion](http://www.thinkingincrowd.me/2016/06/06/How-to-avoid-Stack-overflow-error-on-recursive/)
[How to make long running loop breakable?](http://www.thinkingincrowd.me/2016/06/05/How-to-make-long-running-loop-breakable/)

Answer (score 0):

i did not try this but using an async function that handles the mapping part, then call that function in every iteration with necessary information (index, array item etc.) wont help?

Comment: It can be a comment on this question. please clearly answer the question with an explicit solution.